# Como selecionar automaticamente o primeiro item de um PopupMenu

Tags: delphi

Possuo uma tela onde um popupMenu é aberto através do enter como tecla de atalho. Meu problema é que não consigo fazer com que a primeira opção seja pré-selecionada para ser ativada com um Enter.
Resumindo: Gostaria que ao exibir o popupMenu o enter "clicasse" no primeiro item popup.

Comment: Você queria que com o Enter ele selecionasse a opção ou chamasse o evento da primeira opção?... porque senão você pode chama o evento do OnClick daquela opção do PopupMenu ao clicar no enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após mais algumas pesquisas e testes cheguei a seguinte solução. No evento `OnPopup` inserir o código

```
keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

Esse código simula o pressionamento da "seta para baixo" selecionando o primeiro item da lista. A primeira linha "pressiona" o botão e a segunda "solta".

Answer (score 0):

Em seu `popupMenu` adicione o código abaixo no evento `onPopup`, ou seja, quando mostrar o `popupMenu` automaticamente ira selecionar a primeira opção:

```
PopupMenu1.Items[0].Click;
```

Dessa forma fica mais dinâmico, não importa qual o nome do método que ira chamar no primeiro item, automaticamente seja clicado.

Comment: sua ideia tem um problema, como o comando que você adicionou está no `onPopup` ele sempre será chamado antes que o próprio popup apareça e como disse a primeira opção é a mais usada, mas as vezes o necessário é usar outra função e não a primeira.

Comment: Vou ver outra solução seg..ou terça posto